# Show a hidden div tag when page has loaded using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a webpage that calls a javascript file (jQuery)

The file has the `$(document).ready(function(){` wrapper.

I have a `DIV` tag setup on the page that is hidden

```
<div id="productOne" style="display: none;">Product Two</div>
```

Within my JS file, any attempt to show the DIV tag is not working

```
$('#productOne').show();
```

Is my code in the wrong event? Or is the syntax incorrect?

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: No errors in console and yes, it is inside the doc ready wrapper

Comment: simply use hidden on your tag .. it will work well with jquery show and hide function

Answer (score 2):

Try `$('#productOne').show();` (note the `lowercase` 'p')

Comment: Spot on. JavaScript is case sensitive!

Comment: Sorry for the typo - amended the P to lowercase - still does not work

Comment: @Mike Your code should work. Other than this casing problem, there is nothing wrong in your code. Replicate your problem in a fiddle or something.

Answer (score 0):

Check the id of the div. In your HTML it is ***"productOne"*** and in your jQuery code it is `$('#ProductOne')`.

The ***"p"*** of product should be *small* in jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

Hie,

Check this out if works for you

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#productOne').css("display", "block");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of style = display: none , simply use hidden

```
<div id="productOne" hidden">Product Two</div>
```

Comment: Have you understood the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some spelling mistake
Here is working script. Compare it with yours.

If everything is the same, try to console log something from your file, maybe there is a loading issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#hidden-elem").show();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="hidden-elem" style="display:none;">
  Hello
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if jQuery is loaded or not:

```
if (window.jQuery) {  
   alert("loaded");  
} else {
   alert("not loaded");
}
```

You may try that to test if your jquery is not called before the tag was completely loaded. I had similar issue when i was writing a plugin for sliding image gallery, but i was working with pictures. So try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#productOne").load(function () {
          $(this).show();
    });
});
```

If this works, you have a problem in your syntax or you have other problem with something else like use of same names on the page. Give a whole code to find the bug. Thank you, hopefully this will help.